# SqlServerMetadataExtensions.SqlServer for EntityFrameworkCore 3.x

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0, ef-core-3.1

In a .NET Framework 4.8 project I've used EntityFrameworkCore 2.x with following extension .SqlServer() from Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerMetadataExtensions

```
var entityType = this.Context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T)).SqlServer(); 
var schema = entityType.Schema;
var tableName = entityType.TableName;
```

This worked fine but now code doesn't build anymore on .net core 3.x because .SqlServer() extensionmethod could not be found.
Has this been moved to another assembly in efcore 3.x ? As I can't seem to find anything about this to get it working.

Comment: No more `Relational()`, `SqlServer()` etc. Remove them and look for extension methods directly on metadata type, e.g. `GetSchema`, `GetTableName` etc.

Comment: super! thanks @IvanStoev